# This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key featured

Tags: objective-c, ios

I suspect some code is trying to use my `FooterArchiveView` similar to a `NSDictionary` so I tried using breakpoints to find the bottleneck but my breakpoints are sending me on a wild goose chase into system files like `UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue`. What should I do?

```
2012-03-08 08:35:55.417 JOM App[44161:207] Uncaught exception: [<FooterArchiveView 0x9b27770> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key featured.
2012-03-08 08:35:55.420 JOM App[44161:207] Stack trace: (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0169c06e __exceptionPreprocess + 206
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01c50d0a objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0169bf11 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x00f89032 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x00efaf7b _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 136
    5   Foundation                          0x00efaeeb -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 287
    6   UIKit                               0x00628268 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) setValue:forKey:] + 168
    7   Foundation                          0x00f15d60 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 393
    8   UIKit                               0x0080891a -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x0169de1a -[NSObject performSelector:] + 58
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x01607821 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 273
    11  UIKit                               0x0080746e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1178
    12  UIKit                               0x00809010 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 157
    13  JOM App                             0x0000e9ca -[ContentView setContent:] + 1258
    14  JOM App                             0x0000c906 -[NavigationView devotionsTUI:] + 390
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0169dec9 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 73
    16  UIKit                               0x005ec5c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
    17  UIKit                               0x005ec55a -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    18  UIKit                               0x00691b76 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    19  UIKit                               0x0069203f -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 503
    20  UIKit                               0x006912fe -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 549
    21  UIKit                               0x00611a30 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 513
    22  UIKit                               0x00611c56 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 273
    23  UIKit                               0x005f8384 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 464
    24  UIKit                               0x005ebaa9 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 8196
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x02589fa9 PurpleEventCallback + 1274
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x016701c5 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x015d5022 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 146
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x015d390a __CFRunLoopRun + 2218
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x015d2db4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 212
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x015d2ccb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    31  GraphicsServices                    0x02588879 GSEventRunModal + 207
    32  GraphicsServices                    0x0258893e GSEventRun + 114
    33  UIKit                               0x005e9a9b UIApplicationMain + 1175
    34  JOM App                             0x000027d2 main + 178
    35  JOM App                             0x00002715 start + 53
    36  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

Comment: i think your xib has an extra element that is connected to a non-existent "featured" outlet or even vice-versa. Either way the "key" to your solution is "featured" here.

Comment: The error could be an undefined key. *setValue:forUndefinedKey:*. Maybe you have misspelled a property name. Provide some code if possible. It could be difficult to fix without it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*"This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key featured."* means that a class is trying to set a property on an object through key-value coding, only to find that it cannot.  This most often occurs when you've defined an outlet, connected it in a nib, then removed the outlet from your code, leaving a dangling connection in the nib.  When the nib is deserialised, it tries to connect up the outlet using key-value coding and you see the error above.

Comment: You saved me soooo much time, Jim!